# Loop over multiple List simultaneously in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I like to loop over multiple list simultaneously as below:

```
def p = ["A", "B", "C"]
def q = ["d", "f", "g"]
for (x,y in p,q) {

   println x
   println y

}
```

I can do something like below:

```
def p = ["A", "B", "C"]
def q = ["d", "f", "g"]
for (i=0; i<q.size(); i++) {

   println p[i]
   println q[i]

}
```

but I would love to know the solution in previous format. Any idea how to achieve the same in groovy?

Comment: Does my answer solve the problem?

Answer (score 15):

You can try `transpose`:

```
def p = ["A", "B", "C"];
def q = ["d", "f", "g"];
for (i in [p,q].transpose()) {
    println i[0]
    println i[1]
}
```

Comment: Or `[p,q].transpose().each { a, b -> println a ; println b }`

Comment: @tim_yates you should put this comment as an answer so we could upvote this